# trying to access Django Admin docs raises no reverse match error

Tags: python, django, django-admin, django-urls

I'm trying to generate docs for my Admin so I installed docutils and added the code:

```py
# installed apps
[
    'jazzmin',
    'admin_numeric_filter',
    'django.contrib.admindocs',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    # rest of installed apps...
]
# in my urls
url(r'^admin/doc/', include('django.contrib.admindocs.urls')),
```

But I'm getting the following error when trying to access the docs:

```
NoReverseMatch at /admin/doc/
Reverse for 'app_list' with keyword arguments '{'app_label': 'auth'}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['admin/(?P<app_label>consumer_api|users|authtoken)/$']
```

urls.py file:

```py
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/doc/', include('django.contrib.admindocs.urls')),
    # ADMIN
    path('admin/', consumer_admin.urls),
    # DOCS
    path('schema/', SpectacularAPIView.as_view(), name='schema'),
    path('docs/swagger', PermittedSwagger.as_view(url_name='schema'), name='swagger-ui'),
    path('docs/redoc/', PermittedReDoc.as_view(url_name='schema'), name='redoc'),
    # AUTH
    url(r'auth/', include('users.urls')),
    # ENDPOINTS
    path('', include('consumer_api.urls'))
]
```

Comment: Do you have a url pattern ```url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls)``` in ```urlpatterns``` list ? Please post urls.py file code.

Comment: Can you please place this ```url(r'^admin/doc/', include('django.contrib.admindocs.urls')),``` at the first position in url_patterns list and then try to access the docs?

Comment: @AmandeepSinghSawhney it was there, these patterns are after I removed it, will update but the bug sticks